# Запятая между предложениями с общим вводным словом?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, ссп, и

Почему запятая под номером 3 верна? Как мне кажется, «к счастью» является здесь общим вводным словом, поэтому перед союзом **и** запятая в сложносочиненном предложении не ставится. Тем не менее ответ с этой запятой выделен как верный.

> К счастью,(1) окраины ледяных полей были сильно поломаны,(2) айсберги
> отсутствовали,**(3)** и только иногда(4) гряды мелкого льда,(5)
> нагроможденные местами(6) на полях,(7) представляли серьезную опасность.
> ([ссылка](https://quizizz.com/admin/quiz/5e7f463793ce2a001da75c6a/-))

Comment: Вы уверены, что "к счастью" может относиться к тому, что представляет опасность?

Comment: Лада, "к счастью" здесь может быть общим вводным, но совершенно не обязано им быть. Всё зависит от того, что хотел сказать автор. А у автора (В.А. Обручева) предложение выглядело чуть иначе (Вы скопировали цитату из недобросовестного источника), и с запятой оно смотрится лучше, чем без неё.

Comment: Насколько я поняла, это учебное задание, где пропущены все запятые. В ответе к заданию указано, что запятая (3) ставится, но автору вопроса не очень понятна причина постановки запятой. В авторском тексте запятая стоит, это можно посмотреть по источнику.

Comment: Итак, в разных изданиях запятая ставится или не ставится. Тогда надо поискать более верный источник с авторским выбором. Редакторы могли позже убрать запятую, исходя из своих представлений об оформлении текста по формальному правилу.

Answer (score 2):

В. Обручев, Плутония.

*Матросы с длинными баграми стояли у обоих бортов, чтобы отталкивать судно от напиравших на него льдин. К счастью, окраины ледяных полей были уже сильно **полОманы**, айсберги **отсУтствовали**, **и только иногда** гряды мелкого **льдА**, **нагромождЁнные местами на полях,** представляли более серьезную **опАсность**.*

Примечание. В предложении показана расстановка тонических ударений без логического выделения. Но при чтении текста  ударение может смещаться внутри фразы для логического выделения слов. Например, можно выделить ударением  "только иногда", но можно и не выделять, а поставить ударение в конце этой фразы на "льда". Но обособленный оборот обязательно выделен ударением, поэтому без паузы перед третьим предложением не обойтись.

**ОТВЕТ**

В этом предложении при наличии общего вводного слова запятая под цифрой 3 ставится **обязательно в виде исключения**. Объединению предложений препятствует **обособленный оборот** в середине второго предложения.

Я предполагаю, что в таких случаях решение будет **однозначным**, а не спорным (как указано во втором ответе).

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ**

1. Правило Розенталя http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

   2. Перед союзами и, да (в значении и), или, либо запятая не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения объединены каким-либо общим элементом.4) Общим может быть вводное слово, словосочетание или предложение:  К счастью, пожар был замечен вовремя и налицо оказались нужные средства для его тушения — отношение говорящего к высказыванию, выражаемое посредством вводного слова, распространяется на обе его части.
2. Итак, **вводное слово** может быть общим элементом, а как это определить? По семантике? Давайте попробуем:  я убираю все распространители и максимально упрощаю предложение.

***К счастью, лед был поломан, айсберги отсутствовали и опасные нагромождения были редкими.***  Здесь вполне можно не ставить замыкающую запятую, но смысл сообщения не изменился.

Значит, только по семантике решать задачу нельзя, надо учитывать структуру.  В заданном предложении объединению может препятствовать сочетание «***только иногда»***  – здесь желательна  остановка голоса (и постановка запятой) для перехода к отдельному сообщению.

3. Но есть еще более важный фактор – осложненность (**не распространенность, а именно осложненность!**) третьего предложения. Его вообще **нельзя прочесть без паузы**,  так как там есть **обособленный оборот** – замыкающее предложение обычно простое, хотя распространенным оно может быть.
4. Таким образом, мы делаем **вывод**: при решении вопроса об общем элементе нужно учитывать **дополнительные факторы**, которые могут препятствовать объединению.

Говорит ли об этом **Розенталь?** Он касается темы, когда рассматривает придаточное предложение как общий элемент, находя формальные грамматические признаки для постановки запятой. Но на практике становится очевидным, что этот вопрос решается для всех видов общих элементов.

Comment: Вы выделяете "только иногда" интонационно (с более сильным ударением на "иногда"), а у Обручева интонация совсем другая: на отрезке "и только иногда гряды мелкого льда" интонация возрастает, достигая максимума на слове "льда". Смысл здесь не в том, что "к счастью, опасность была маловероятной", а в том, что "но, к сожалению, иногда всё же было опасно". Я в этом уверен, потому что иначе слово "более" выглядит в оригинальном тексте стилистически корявенько. А в ОГЭ слово "более" убрали и в предложение вполне можно вложить Ваш смысл. Но тогда и запятая там не нужна — в этом я согласен с Ладой.

Comment: Спасибо вам за комментарий (вы редко уделяете мне внимание, а мне оно всегда приятно). Попробую рассказать об интонации. На самом деле я вообще не использую логическое выделение слов  в третьем  предложении.  Я полагаю, что наречие препятствует  произношению без паузы, но на нем не ставлю ударения. Но в настоящий момент в качестве основного ФАКТОРА  для постановки запятой считаю наличие обособленного оборота. Как прочитать текст без паузы перед третьим предложением, если оно само содержит паузы для выделения причастного оборота. Это предложение должно быть самостоятельным, отделенным запятой.

Answer (score 1):

Вот описание ситуации, в которое входит и указанное предложение (выделены отсутствующие слова).

> Капитану потребовалась вся его опытность, чтобы пробиваться медленно вперед, лавируя между полями, отступая, поворачивая то направо, то налево. Матросы с длинными баграми стояли у обоих бортов, чтобы отталкивать судно от напиравших на него льдин. *К счастью, окраины ледяных полей были **уже** сильно поломаны, айсберги отсутствовали, и только иногда гряды мелкого льда, нагроможденные местами на полях, представляли **более** серьезную опасность.*
> [В. А. Обручев. Плутония](https://books.google.ee/books?id=j0MzDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT393&lpg=PT393&dq=%D0%9A%20%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E,%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B,%20%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8,%20%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=Cy2IqyG5vp&sig=ACfU3U3cQ4mwDAiTVfVxGjnOG0iF4YSaaQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4psyc9o7wAhWttYsKHdSNCkYQ6AEwB3oECAYQAw#v=onepage&q=%D0%9A%20%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E%2C%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%2C%20%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0&f=false)

Интересно то, что во многих других изданиях указанная вами запятая отсутствует (можно посмотреть [здесь](https://books.google.ee/books?id=OSktuN34hM4C&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35&dq=%D0%9A%20%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E,%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B,%20%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8,%20%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=Kmisj8mzR8&sig=ACfU3U1KZC-odPcZnM9hp3ewfJ0_Mobp8Q&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4psyc9o7wAhWttYsKHdSNCkYQ6AEwCHoECAQQAw#v=onepage&q=%D0%9A%20%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E%2C%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%2C%20%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0&f=false) и [здесь](https://books.google.ee/books?id=8TcPDhUbQ8MC&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=%D0%9A%20%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E,%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B,%20%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8,%20%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=pMk6ITuE7_&sig=ACfU3U1jlv92t1L8uqhWys9vgBvaXqhIIA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4psyc9o7wAhWttYsKHdSNCkYQ6AEwCXoECAUQAw#v=onepage&q=%D0%9A%20%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E%2C%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%2C%20%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0&f=false)).
Интересно то, что в большинстве тестов рекомендуется эту запятую ставить.
Все это говорит о том, что запятая спорна.

***К счастью**, только иногда гряды мелкого льда, нагроможденные местами на полях, представляли более серьезную опасность.*
Можно ли так сказать? Я думаю, можно. В ситуации, которую описывает автор, *счастьем* было и то, что *только иногда* гряды представляли опасность. Тогда отсутствие запятой оправдано.
Но из-за удаленности вводного слова и распространенности третьего предложения (а также в отрыве же от предыдущего контекста) считается, что запятая должна быть.

Comment: Римма,  у меня к вам такие вопросы. (1)  Почему вы считаете, что удаленность вводного слова может быть  причиной постановки запятой? Разве в каких-то источниках называется этот фактор?    (2) Как вы думаете, пауза там делается?  Вы ее слышите или она тоже кажется вам спорной, как и запятая?

Answer (score 1):

Ответы на комментарии

**I.** *В авторском тексте запятая стоит, это можно посмотреть по источнику.*
Теперь же, когда приведены ссылки, в которых пунктуация различна, надо, выходит, искать источник с авторской пунктуацией.

**II.** *Редакторы могли позже убрать запятую, исходя из своих представлений...*
Но ведь могло быть и с точностью до наоборот: редакторы могли **поставить** запятую, основываясь на [правилах 1956 года](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/) (роман написан в 1915 году; первая публикация — 1924 год).

**III.** *Почему вы считаете, что удаленность вводного слова может быть причиной постановки запятой?*
Дело в том, что ни в каком из правил, рассказывающих об общем вводном слове (или сочетании, или предложении), нет ни одного примера с тремя предложениями (во всяком случае, мне не попадались) — везде только два.

Вот "самые крупные".
Во-первых, класс уже сформирован и ученики приступили к занятиям.
К счастью, пожар был замечен вовремя и средства для тушения были исправны.
По словам охотников, зверь в этих лесах вывелся и птица исчезла.
По мнению бабушек у подъезда, она не придерживалась строгих моральных норм и ее двери были всегда открыты для посетителей.

Я имела в виду именно вот эту удаленность, когда в учебной программе вообще не рассматриваются такие особенные предложения. Получается, что школьник, зная только **о двух** предложениях, возможных при общем вводном слове, практически автоматом должен ставить запятую перед третьим.

**IV.** *Как вы думаете, пауза там делается? Вы ее слышите или она тоже кажется вам спорной, как и запятая?*
Мне кажется, что возможно прочитать и без паузы, остановиться только перед причастным оборотом (многое ведь зависит от представлений автора).
Есть предложения, в которых на письме запятые имеются, а в речи паузы нет (например, с одиночными деепричастиями).

Comment: Спасибо, Римма за ответы, все-таки вас нельзя отнести к группе молчаливых, как я думала, достойное поведение.  (1)  Надо искать источник. (2) Постановка запятой в авторском варианте могла основываться на интонации, на наличии паузы. В редакциях после 1956 года можно было только убрать лишнюю запятую для соответствия правилам. Исключения там не рассматриваются. (3) Школьник уверенно относит вводные слово к третьему предложению.

Comment: 4) Дело не только в паузах: второе полноценное ударение будет делаться на обороте при отсутствии запятой, потом еще раз в конце предложения. Странная получается интонация для предложения, которое нужно прочитать в одну фразу с первым предложением, оно просто распадается на части. Обратите, пожалуйста, внимание на мой вопрос и пример (3) из Розенталя. Там ясно видно, как оборот влияет на постановку запятой.

Comment: Вот видите, Sharon, можно было мне и промолчать — все равно ведь мое мнение Вас не устроило. Я просто рассуждала как обычный, почти грамотный человек. На основе обычных школьных знаний.

Comment: А вот и нет!  С одной стороны, мне хочется хотя бы с кем-то поговорить,  желающих обычно не случается, но это только с одной стороны. Обычно происходит так: я мало с чем соглашаюсь, но потом понимаю, что меняется моя собственная точка зрения.  Начинаешь видеть нечто новое, ранее не замеченное, будто смотришь другими глазами.

Comment: А в этой теме мое мнение вообще принципиально изменилось. Хотела доказать, что распространенность не может быть решающим фактором, решила убрать наречие и прочитать предложение без паузы, а оно вообще не читается, оборот мешает. Так что «открытие» мое по справедливости ваше наполовину.  Вот как важны для меня те мнения, с которыми я не соглашаюсь.

Comment: В таком случае я рада, что моё мнение и мои ограниченные знания хоть в чём-то являются полезными. Вы только с высказыванием _своего_ мнения будьте чуть помягче — ведь многие из нас уже _взрослые_ люди (это, конечно же, моё личное суждение). С уважением...

Comment: Спасибо, учту ваши замечания. У вас прекрасные знания по теме русского правописания. Вы хотите, чтобы я вам это сказала. Вот, говорю. Еще раз большое спасибо. Честно говоря, наши участники каждый день дарят мне свои знания, даже не подозревая об этом. Одну из ситуаций я объяснила, но  это отнюдь не редкость. Мне иногда кажется, что приобретаю я больше, чем отдаю.