# В каком случае при наличии общего элемента в сложносочиненном предложении запятая ставится как исключение

Tags: запятые, ссп

Как известно, при наличии общего элемента в ССП запятая перед союзом И обычно не ставится, но возможны исключения под влиянием различных факторов.

Версия такова: Если **в середине второго предложения** есть обособленный оборот или придаточное предложение, то  запятая перед ним **ставится обязательно** – это тот фактор, который препятствует объединению предложений.

Вывод я сделала для себя, отвечая на следующий вопрос [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464207/Запятая-между-предложениями-с-общим-вводным-словом](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464207/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC)

Это объясняется тем, что **осложненное внутренними паузами** предложение невозможно прочитать в одну фразу с первым предложением. Но  вызвать кого-либо на дискуссию сложно, голосование же скорее всего будет «молчаливым», на комментарии ответов тоже нет.

Тогда мне хотелось бы увидеть **примеры без запятой**, таких примеров я не нашла у Розенталя. Там второе предложение или (1) **простое** (наиболее частотный вариант), или (2) иногда можно встретить осложняющий оборот/придаточное  (только не вводное слово), но **в конце** предложения (тогда интонация не препятствует объединению).

**Примеры у Розенталя:**

Пример (1) **У Гаврилы** смешно надулись щёки, оттопырились губы и суженные глаза как-то чересчур часто и смешно помаргивали (М. Г.);

Пример (2)  **Согласно общепризнанным нормам международного права**, открытое море свободно для всех наций и все государства обязаны воздерживаться от всяких актов, **способных** причинить ущерб его использованию другими государствами.

Пример (3) **Запятая ставится**: **По утрам** кумысный домик привлекал людей со слабыми лёгкими, и пятна солнца, **прорвавшиеся** сквозь листву на столики, освещали около недопитых стаканов неподвижно лежащие бледные длиннопалые руки.

У Розенталя это предложение упрощено и **запятой нет:** **По утрам** кумысный домик привлекал людей со слабыми лёгкими и пятна солнца… освещали около недопитых стаканов неподвижно лежащие бледные длиннопалые руки (Фед.);

Если  вам встретятся **такие примеры**, скажите об этом, пожалуйста.

Спасибо.